# How to position labels for plotbands on y axis in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

This [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/LKtpc/2/) is a similar example from highcharts.com which i'm working on. I'm trying to place the labels for plot bands on y axis. But as you can see the labels are overlapping on the chart which isn't that good. If i wanna color the labels with the same color of the corresponding plotbands, the label doesn't show up. Is there a way to place it completely outside without overlapping?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not possible to do it yet.
If you add labels to the plotbands it will overlap them.
You can align your labels but if you set `x` more than your chart width, it will not appear on your chart.
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LKtpc/4/)

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution is to add right margin to the chart, and move the labels over.

Add a marginRight to the chart, and on each label, use x to determine its starting x position.

```
marginRight:110
```

and

`x: 90` on each label.

http://jsfiddle.net/7xb1Lgx6/ the fiddle.